# Jquery tabs, open a tab from a link inside a tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jquery tabs to display some content, and I need to make a link inside the tab to open another tab, my jquery knowledge is very limited, so I am posting my code, so you can check and see what I can do?

This is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$(".tab_content").hide(); 
    $(".tab_content").css({
        'display':'block',
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':'-999em',
        'left':'-999em'
    });
    //$(".tab_content:first").show(); 
    $(".tab_content:first").css({
        'top':'350px',
        'left':'50px',
        'width':'660px'
    });
    firstTabHeight = $(".tab_content:first").height();
    $(".tab_content:first").parent().css('height',firstTabHeight);

    $("#nav-portfolio ul li").click(function() {
        $("#nav-portfolio ul li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        //$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        $(".tab_content").css({
            'display':'block',
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'-999em',
            'left':'-999em'
        });

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).hide(); 
        //$(".tab_content").css({
        //  'opacity':'0',
        //});
        //var tabHeight = $(activeTab).height();
        //$('#colLeft').height(tabHeight);
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        thisTabHeight = $(activeTab).height();
        $(activeTab).css({
            'display':'block',
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'width':'660px'
        });
    activeTabHeight = $(activeTab).height();
    $(".tab_content:first").parent().css('height',activeTabHeight);

   return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click function to the link inside your tab to call the click function of the tab you want to go to. Eg, if you wanted the link to trigger the second tab:

```
$('#this_is_the_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the normal link function from happening
    $("#nav-portfolio ul li:nth-child(2)").click() // call click event on the second tab
});
```